# I got the messge in log while run the emulator == emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0

Tags: android, android-emulator

emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0

The above error come in loop while run our emulator in android studio

emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0
emulator: Trying to vcpu execute at eip:1000f0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: It's an issue with intel's 7th gen processor

Comment: @JeroenHeier: There is no issue with the question. It's absolutely fine.